# Call Flash As3 function from Javascript In Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, google-chrome-extension, externalinterface

I am developing Radio player extension For Google Chrome.
I am using flash in my application and want to call method Mute from my Javascript code.

I know that i can use ExternalInterface, but it's not working in local Environment.
How can i call method from local swf file?.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not having any luck getting ExternalInterface to work in a swf running within a Chrome Extension.  Curiously, ExternalInterface.avaiable is true.  I have set "allowScriptAccess" to true.  ExternalInteraface.call("someFunction") from within the swf seems to have no effect.  After adding a callback using ExteranlInterface.addCallback("someOtherFunction"), within js there is no function "someOtherFunction" associated with the embedded swf.  I think we are out of luck.